# airflow run dag with arguments on remote webserver

Tags: airflow

I would like to kick off dags on a remote webserver. These dags require arguments in order to make sense. Locally, I use a command like this:

```
airflow trigger_dag dag_id --conf '{"parameter":"~/path" }'
```

The problem is that this assumes I'm running locally. How can I trigger a dag on a remote airflow server with arguments? I realize I could use the ui to hit the play button, but that doesn't allow you to pass arguments that I am aware of.

Comment: Maybe experimental API would be an option for you https://airflow.apache.org/api.html ? Alternatively you could use SSH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example url:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/experimental/dags/<dag_id>/dag_runs
```

Example post payload(application/json):

```
{"conf":"{\"client\":\"popsicle\"}"}
```

Note that the embedded conf object must be a string, not an object.